# How to parse a decimal fraction into Rational in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, decimal, rational-numbers

I've been participating in [a programming contest](http://codeforces.com/contest/105) and [one of the problems](http://codeforces.com/contest/105/problem/A)' input data included a fractional number in a decimal format: `0.75` is one example.

Parsing that into `Double` is trivial (I can use `read` for that), but the loss of precision is painful. One needs to be very careful with `Double` comparisons (I wasn't), which seems redundant since one has `Rational` data type in Haskell.

When trying to use that, I've discovered that to `read` a `Rational` one has to provide a string in the following format: `numerator % denominator`, which I, obviously, do not have.

So, the question is:

**What is the easiest way to parse a decimal representation of a fraction into `Rational`?**

The number of external dependencies should be taken into consideration too, since I can't install additional libraries into the online judge.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function you want is `Numeric.readFloat`:

```
Numeric Data.Ratio> fst . head $ readFloat "0.75" :: Rational
3 % 4
```

Comment: you might want to add `readSigned` if you want to be able to read negative numbers: `fst . head $ readSigned readFloat "-3.14" :: Rational`

Answer (score 3):

How about the following (GHCi session):

```
> :m + Data.Ratio
> approxRational (read "0.1" :: Double) 0.01
1 % 10
```

Of course you have to pick your epsilon appropriately.

Comment: This is a good idea! I think this should be used instead of `toRational` in most circumstances!

Comment: Unfortunately, the choice of epsilon is not obvious here. For example, `approxRational 0.999 0.0001` is `909 % 910`, which is not what I want. The proper epsilon to use in this case is `0.000001` (precision squared?)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'd get extra points in the contest for implementing it yourself:

```
import Data.Ratio ( (%) )

readRational :: String -> Rational
readRational input = read intPart % 1 + read fracPart % (10 ^ length fracPart)
  where (intPart, fromDot) = span (/='.') input
        fracPart           = if null fromDot then "0" else tail fromDot
```

Comment: I don't think so. In such contests only the submission time and correctness matters. Nice solution still, short enough to code in an emergency.